# Find a text by its text with can contain noise

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to find a link which contains a text and some noise by BeautifulSoup4:

```
<a href="#">
  <span>gggggggggggg</span>
  Some text123
  <div>fdsfdsfdsfd</div>
  <span> fdsfdsfdsfd</span>
</a>
```

When I'm trying to find it by "Some text123", it fails:

```
soup123.find("a", "Some text123") # => NoneType
```

What is the solution for this?

**update:**

The "a" isn't a single one, there can be many of them. But the "a" with "Some text123" is unique.

Comment: Try with `soup123.find("a", text=re.compile("Some text123") )`

Comment: please post real html code

Comment: @Fejs  i tried and got nothing

Comment: @Fejs, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might suit your needs. It simply finds all `a` tags and determines if the search text you are looking for is present. It then displays the associated `href` tag for any matching entries:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
    <a href="#1"><span>gggggggggggg</span>Some text123<div>fdsfdsfdsfd</div><span> fdsfdsfdsfd</span></a>
    <a href="#2"><span>gggggggggggg</span>Some text124<div>fdsfdsfdsfd</div><span> fdsfdsfdsfd</span></a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
search = "Some text123"

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    if search in a.text:
        print a['href']
```

So for my example, it would display:

```
#1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working solution (tested):

```
a_tag = soup.find('a', text=re.compile("Some text123")).parent
```

If You're not getting this output:

```
<a href="#">
<span>gggggggggggg</span>
  Some text123
  <div>fdsfdsfdsfd</div>
<span> fdsfdsfdsfd</span>
</a>
```

after using my command, then You don't have input which You expect in `soup`. If this part of code is generated by JS, You won't be able to get it with `BS`.